# Why is my Rspec test on length validation failing ? (rails/guard/rspec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, guard

I have a very simple test on a Deal model that keeps failing and I can't understand why.

My Deal model:

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :admin_user, :foreign_key => 'admin_user_id'

attr_accessible :url_path,
              :country,
              :title,
              :description,
              :twitter_msg,
              :image_url,
              :prelaunch_date,
              :deal_launch_date,
              :deal_end_date,
              :featured,
              :admin_user_id
              :as => :admin_user

validates :title,
          presence: true,
          length: { maximum: 200 }
```

The test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Deal do

let(:admin_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user) }

    before(:each) do
@attr = {
          url_path:    "lorem ipsum",
  country:     "France",
  title:       "lorem ipsum",
  description: "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum",
  twitter_msg: "lorem ipsum",
  image_url:   "lorem ipsum",
  prelaunch_date:     1.days.from_now.change(hour: 10),
  deal_launch_date:   3.days.from_now.change(hour: 10),
  deal_end_date:      15.days.from_now.change(hour: 10),
  featured:           true,
  admin_user_id: 1
}
```

end

```
describe "tests on deal models validations for TITLES" do
it { should validate_presence_of(:title) }
it { should_not allow_value(" ").for(:title) }

it "should reject deals with title that is too long" do
  long = "a" * 201
  hash = @attr.merge(:title => long)
  Deal.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:title)
end    
end
```

and the test fail with
"Deal tests on deal's models validations for TITLES should reject deals with title that is too long
     Failure/Error: Deal.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:title)
       expected 1 error on :title, got 2
=> **i don't get why i have 2 errors**. i should get only one and my test would be passing!

The strangest thing: 
- when I do `rspec spec` it fails
- then if I change in my validates the number of characters to 195 and in my test to 196, it then passes
- but then, the next time I relaunch guard or my server, then it fails again
and if I change again to 190 and 191, it then works again, but as soon as I restart guard or my server

I tried this many times and it's always the same problem. I don't understand, it seems guard or my server is the problem.

Does anybody have a clue to why it happens and how I can correct this?

Comment: post your `spec_helper.rb` as well. I think the problem is there. Something loads your model twice and this adds the same validation. Two validations adds two errors.

Comment: You might want to print out the two errors as well

Comment: @gotva sorry for delay, i updated the question with my spec_helper file

Comment: @PeterAlfvin i don't know how to do it. what should i add in my rspec file in the test so that it gives me back the errors messages?

Comment: I have the same problem when `load model` duplicate validation and as a result duplicate validation errors. Unfortunately I did not manage to solve it. But I am sure your problem is in this line. Try to deep in this direction.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin i used exactly d= Game.new(hash)
      d.valid?
      puts d.errors.full_messages.join("\n"). and the error the message i get is "Title Your title must be between 4 and 200 characters
Title Your title must be between 4 and 200 characters" so it repeats two times the error message.

Comment: Where did you get the instructions for what to include in the `Spork.prefork` block?  I don't have `require 'rails/application'` in mine and I wonder if that's perhaps the cause of the duplication.

Comment: @gotva thanks . you were completely right and thanks for helping me track down the real pb: it was indeed load modal...the only way i managed was to remove it and use another way to guard models i followed this: http://my.rails-royce.org/2012/01/14/reloading-models-in-rails-3-1-when-usign-spork-and-cache_classes-true/

Answer (score 4):

You could use the shoulda matcher to test validations:

```
it { should ensure_length_of(:title).is_at_most(200) }
```

Answer (score 2):

With Shoulda Matchers gem installed, you can do a:

```
it { should validate_length_of(:title).is_at_most(200) }
```